# Python - Is there a way to bypass python's http middle-man attack protection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

So I am trying to emulate my auth that I made in python, it uses api requests and it uses the "requests" module to execute the get requests. My issue is when I open HTTP Debugger (same thing happens with Fiddler) and try to execute the auth i get a ssl error from the requests module, i can disable that by adding "verify=False" but thats not the solution im looking for, I read that the cause of that is a middle-man attack protection that was added to the requests/urllib3 module. So is there anyway I can bypass that in a compiled script? (The python code has been compiled to .exe)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You HAVE to use "man-in-the-middle" code if you want to use an HTTP debugger on an SSL connection.  Otherwise, the debugger isn't involved in the key exchange and can't decrypt the HTTPS traffic.

Comment: The `requests` module needs to trust the proxy's SSL certificate, so it can decrypt the SSL response from the server (as if it were a client) and re-encrypt it to send to the client (as if it were a server).  The bad news is that this probably isn't any easier to do than adding `verify=False` since the module is compiled into the EXE. The good news is that you may be able to extract the Python files from the EXE since it's not a true compilation (it's really a bundling of the Python interpreter with the source files and libraries it uses).

Comment: @kindall Thanks, I was planning on doing that but ran into more issues when trying it. Mainly when **nuitka** was used for the compiling/converting to exe